# C# async function as Task<int>

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

In the following code:

```
async static Task<int> test(){ 
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: Start 3", DateTime.Now);
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return 3; 
}

List<Task<int>> tasks2 = new List<Task<int>> {
    test(),
    new Task<int>( delegate { Console.WriteLine("{0}: Start 3", DateTime.Now); Task.Delay(3000).Wait(); return 3; } ),
    new Task<int>( delegate { Console.WriteLine("{0}: Start 1", DateTime.Now); Task.Delay(1000).Wait(); return 1; } ),
};


foreach (var task in tasks2)
    task.Start(); // this cause exception at runtime
```

Why I can't use `test` method as `Task<int>`? If function returns `Task<int>`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mentioned you cannot call `Start` as it was already started. You could still achieve your goals by checking for the status, if that is what you wish for. Please see the updated code below:

```
async static Task<int> test(){ 
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: Start 3", DateTime.Now);
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return 3; 
}


        List<Task<int>> tasks2 = new List<Task<int>> {
           new Task<int>( delegate{ return test().Result;}),
            new Task<int>( delegate { Console.WriteLine("{0}: Start 3", DateTime.Now); Task.Delay(3000).Wait(); return 3; } ),
            new Task<int>( delegate { Console.WriteLine("{0}: Start 1", DateTime.Now); Task.Delay(1000).Wait(); return 1; } ),
            };

foreach (var task in tasks2)
{
        task.Start();
}
```

Comment: I agree, it already started. Is there a way, to pass test function as Task<int> to the  List<Task<int>> ?

Comment: I have updated the List initialization part. You could now call `Start` when you require.

Answer (score 3):

The task returned by `test()` has already started when you invoked `test()`. So you cannot start it again.

Actually, the task returned by `test()` is a promise-style task that does not run on the thread-pool thread in the first place.

You should almost always create tasks that have already started (once they are created).

I.e., you should not use the constructor of `Task` and then call the `Start` method.

Instead, if you want to run the task on a thread-pool thread, use [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: "You should almost always create tasks that have already started (once they are created)." - Why? What if I want to run them latter?

Comment: " the task returned by test() is a promise-style task" - What is this?

Comment: Because `Task.Run` is a better alternative. Take a look at [this article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/02/a-tour-of-task-part-8-starting.html). If you want to create something and start it later, use `Action<T>`, and then start it via `Task.Run` later.

Comment: [Here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/04/a-tour-of-task-part-10-promise-tasks.html) is a good article about promise tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else has pointed out, the task has been set in motion when you called `test()` so you can't start on it again. Give below code a shot to see what's going on.

As you can see, the console output comes for each of the task. Task returned by `test()` is started by calling that method. So, this code only explicitly starts the other tasks that are in `Created` status. Finally, we wait for all tasks to complete by calling `WhenAll()` which in turn returns a task on which we wait. You will notice the longest delay of 3 seconds (of all tasks) before "All done!" is printed.

```
public static class AsyncTest
{
    static async Task<int> test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Start 3", DateTime.Now);
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        return 3;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {

        var tasks2 = new List<Task<int>>
        {
            test(),
            new Task<int>( delegate { Console.WriteLine("{0}: Start 3", DateTime.Now); Task.Delay(3000).Wait(); return 3; } ),
            new Task<int>( delegate { Console.WriteLine("{0}: Start 1", DateTime.Now); Task.Delay(1000).Wait(); return 1; } )
        };

        foreach (var task in tasks2)
        {
            if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Created)
                task.Start();
        }

        Task.WhenAll(tasks2).Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("All done!");
    }
}
```